# inputAccessoryView getting hidden on UISearchBar activation in UISplitViewController

Tags: swift, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, inputaccessoryview

I'm facing an issue - when UISearchBar is activated then inputAccessoryView gets hidden and doesn't show up even after de-activation of UISearchBar searching in iPad.

## Video

[image: InputAccessoryView_Issue]

## Steps to the issue

1. Start UISearchbar editing
2. Cancel UISearchBar editing
3. Observe the inputAccessoryView visibility before and after editing

## Storyboard

[image: Storyboard]

Please find the code in this repo - [InputAccessoryView_Issue](https://github.com/rjt3662/InputAccessoryView_Issue) and feel free to commit your solution in the repo itself or here in Stackoverflow.

TIA

Comment: An inputAccessoryView only appears for a specific responder that is currently the first responder.

Comment: Yes, But I tried making the detailview as first responder when the searchbar ends editing still the inputAccessoryView don't show up.

Comment: You haven't put any relevant code in your question. Edit your question and copy and paste relevant code.

Comment: I found the solution and am posting in the answers. Basically I made first responder the Detail controller and also the detail controller's parent view and it started working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I found was to make the detail controller as first responder immediately after Searchbar ends editing.
Below is the sample code for the same:

```
extension NSNotification.Name {
     static let SearchbarEndEditing = NSNotification.Name("SEARCHBAR_END_EDITING")
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .SearchbarEndEditing, object: nil)
}
```

And in DetailViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(handleSearchbarEndEditing),
                                           name: .SearchbarEndEditing,
                                           object: nil)
}

@objc private func handleSearchbarEndEditing(_ sender: NSNotification) {
    becomeFirstResponder()
    view.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

It worked for me and hopefully, it works for everyone else as well!